# Android Studio - Removed Code Still In Final APK?

Tags: java, android, apk

I had a toast message a few builds ago that said "Failed", I have quadruple checked it is not in the latest version but from time to time I see it on the running app.

Can't find any other cases of this happen and am unable to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very strange my opinion to you.

```
First go to Build(top on the android studio)-> Clean project -> Build APK -> Generate signed APK.
```

If this will not help you than go to.
   app\build\outputs\apk and delete your apk. and again build signed APK.